# LongListSelector in WP8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

I am trying to create my first WP8 application. I have good experience on Silverlight & WPF however this is not a cake for me which I expected :(.
I am making a Create Employ Form in which user entered different information of the employ. I need to show Country List Combobox. I noticed that in WP8, I will have to use LongListSelector but I am confused that how will I display it with my other textboxes etc control into the FORM. LongListSelector work on the full page but I want to show it like a ComboBox in simple window form application. 
I know this is very basic question but I will appreciate for your help.

Comment: find a tutorial....like this one, http://www.wpftutorial.net/

Answer (score 4):

you cant use combobox in wp8 ...

you can use ListPicker it is a new control introduced in wp8 toolkit...
in this if  your list contains less than 5 members than it will show it as dropdown otherwise it will show it as a list on a different page.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Height and Width properties for Lonlistselector or otherwise change the control   ListPicker simmler to CombooBox.